# Regex expression does not work = match found but incorrect value extracted

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have been using this regex for a while and it has been working out very well for me but on one of the strings it did not work out and is giving me strange result. Here is my code:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(line.Trim(), "3(?:\d{10,12}|[\d- _.]{10,16})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

' If successful, write the group.
 If (m.Success) Then
      strTemp = m.Groups(0).Value
 End If
```

My string in question is:

line="SOS International LLC         246326    37-115-20618- -      GB S AAA         3H"

My goal is to detect and extract 37-115-20618

Normally the code above works in similar situation but this particular string seems to land an unexpected and weird result:

m.Groups(0).Value returns the following: "326            37"

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my regex?

Comment: I get `326 37-115-20618-` as a match. Anyway, you need to explain if you want to allow spaces in the input strings, otherwise, Avinash Raj's answer should suffice.

Comment: Note that a `-` not at start or end of the character class (the part between `[ ]`) is treated as a range specifier (the strange "digit to space" in your case). See [regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/kyf5328)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space inside the character class and add a word boundary at the start and at the end.

```
\b3(?:\d{10,12}|[-\d_.]{10,16})\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vV1/6)

Now grab the string you want from group index 0. `\b` matches between a word character (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_`) and a non-word character (*all chars except the word character*).

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me what does boundary do?

Answer (score 2):

A literal dash (`-`) in character classes must be only at begin or in the end: [-\d _.] OR [\d _.-]. Next you can check for word boundary at beginning and in the end of your RE or check for + or other symbols:

```
(?:\b|(?<!\w)[+_])3(?:\d{10,12}|[-\d _.]{10,16})\b
```